# Cordova sunset?

Tags: android, cordova

Recently we updated all plugins for our Cordova Android project. Using cordova-android@12.0.1, the app won't install on a device with Nov 2023 Security Update (Android 14) so guess we just have to wait for Cordova to catch up? Are there any ex-Cordova users that have migrated to a diff't tool for your mobile apps - please share?!?!?